# s3distcp srcPattern not working?

Tags: hadoop, amazon-s3, elastic-map-reduce

I have files like this in S3:

```
1-2013-08-22-22-something
2-2013-08-22-22-something
etc
```

without srcPattern I can get all of the files from the bucket easily but I want to get a specific prefix, for example all of the 1's. I've tried using srcPattern but for some reason it's not picking up any of the files.

My current command is:

```
elastic-mapreduce --jobflow $JOBFLOW --jar /home/hadoop/lib/emr-s3distcp-1.0.jar \
--args '--src,s3n://some-bucket/,--dest,hdfs:///hdfs-input,--srcPattern,[0-9]-.*' \
--step-name "copying over s3 files"
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Turns out you need .* in front of the regex

for example I needed

```
.*[0-9]-.*
```

I'm guessing because the source pattern also includes the bucket name?

Comment: This means we can control files included using regexp on the full path which is nice feature and should be clearly documented.

Comment: I had the same problem and solve using something like: s3-dist-cp --s3Endpoint=s3.amazonaws.com --src=s3://source/ --srcPattern=.*events_2022_03/serial=0000.*|.*events_2022_04/serial=0000.* --dest=hdfs:///user/spark/events/